# C# Recursive Dependency Not Being Found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies

I'm learning C# for a project, and am having a bit of trouble with dependencies. Essentially here is how things are set up:

The project itself, a library called (XMLupdater), depends on NuGet package. I then have another project used to test the above library (which I've called XMLtester). Here is my solution for the test project, with the library added as a dependency in Visual Studio:
[link bc I can't embed images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMg2d.png)

As far as I can tell, everything here is a-ok, but I get an error at runtime saying that it can't find the NuGet package. It says this:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'XmlDiffPatch.Core, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

I've tried everything I can think of to fix this, but it's coming down to the fact that I just don't have much experience with this language and ide, and dependencies can be real strange sometimes. I've asked a couple others to no avail, so I've decided to ask for the sage advice of you folks. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to look what other *.dll files are required in order to load XmlDiffPatch.Core.dll you can use tools like .dot peek or visual studio to see what are those files and add them as references to your project

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have assembly version issue. The assembly referenced in your solution would have different version than what is shown in error message.

There are 2 ways to fix this situation:

1. Get the exact version of assembly that’s shown in the error and add reference to that one.
2. Use bindingRedirect in your config file to tell compiler which version to look for.

For the second option, you can add/update the `<assemblyRedirect` element in the config file of your executing project.

```
<dependentAssembly>  
  <assemblyIdentity name="someAssembly"  
    publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"  
    culture="en-us" />  
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="— add the actual version of the assembly referenced in your project —" />  
</dependentAssembly>
```

> Use the attribute `newVersion` to set version of the XmlDiffPatch.Core referenced in your project.
>
> You can find more details about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions